# Corel Draw X5 Slicing

Tags: slice, coreldraw

I have to slice from "cdr" file to HTML. I search on the web, but i didn't find anything on how to do that.

Does anybody know a tutorial on how to slice from CorelDraw to Html?
It's that even possible or should i convert it somehow in PSD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to file->export->and select psd option and export it, and slice the images using photoshop then use it in html.

If you need layers , go to corel draw tools ->object manager there you have arrange your design in layer format then export it.